# WinForm Application deployment

Tags: winforms, deployment

Dear Gurus,
  We have developed the win for application, which will consume WCF services. application is running smooth. now the question is deployment. 
 need to deply the application in such a way, once u develop the build the MSI should be transfered from machine to machine insteed of all machine hitting the server for new build. can any one guide me how to acheive the

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I assume it's too big to fit on a floppy? I have no idea what you're asking here. And why is this tagged "C" when you describe it as a "WinForms" application?

Answer (score 0):

Use a packaging tool, there is one integrated in Visual Studio. See http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/226587-how-create-msi